# Sum converging a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

Let $X_k$ be independent random variable s.t. $\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\rightarrow_{a.s.} X$. So,

$$X=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (X_k^+ -X_k^-)$$

Is it true that $X=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (X_k^+)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty (X_k^-)$?

In particular, can we say that $E[X]=E[\sum_{k=1}^\infty (X_k^+)]-E[\sum_{k=1}^\infty (X_k^-)]$?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not even true for deterministic sequences. Just consider $$X_k := \frac{(-1)^k}{k},$$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \to 0$, but since both series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k^+$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k^-$ are divergent, the equality $$X = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k^+ - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k^-$$ does not hold.

Comment: Is there a way, however, to bound $E[(\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k)^+]$? I know that $E[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k^+]=\infty$

Comment: @RobertW. So, basically, you are asking me whether we can bound $\infty$ from above...?

Comment: Nope :) I'm asking about $E[(\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k)^+]$ It can be less than $E[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k^+]$...

Comment: @RobertW. Ah, sorry, I missed the brackets. So bound $\mathbb{E}[(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k)^+]$ by what? You don't even assume that the $X_k$ are integrable. For example, if $X_1 := Y$, $X_2=X_3=\ldots=0$ for some $Y \notin L^1$, $Y \geq 0$, then $\mathbb{E}[(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k)^+] = \infty$.

Comment: Oh. that's true. All $X_n$'s are integrable (actually bounded between $-\alpha(n)$ and $\alpha(n)$ s.t. $\alpha(n)\rightarrow \infty$). However, it's possible that $X$ is not integrable and I'm trying to show this.

Comment: Any suggestion/hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: @RobertW. Consider independent $(X_k)_k$ satisfying $\mathbb{P}(X_k = 0) = 1-p_k$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_k=k) = p_k$. Using the Borel-Cantelli theorem, show that $X:=\sum_{k \geq 0} X_k$ converges almost surely if $\sum_k p_k< \infty$. On the other hand, $\mathbb{E}X= \sum_{k \geq 0} k p_k$.

Comment: So, $p_k$ should converge to 0 but not too fast. However, if $E[X_k]=0$ we cannot use the same trick isn't it? (Sorry, that I misled you by not stating all the details)

Comment: @RobertW. This is correct. But you didn't mention this....

Comment: So, in zero expectation case I need to show that the "positive" part of the sum diverge to infinity (and negative as well); and the problem is that I cannot switch summation and expectation. So, actually the question is if there is a way to estimate $\mathbb{E}[(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k)^+]$ somehow...

Comment: @RobertW. I guess, it would be a good idea to open a new question and state there what you exactly want to show (including all assumptions...).

Comment: Sure. Thank's a lot.

Comment: The new question is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013118/sum-converging-a-s-contd